# jQuery on click event not working on toggled class

Tags: jquery

I have tried "on","live", and "delegate" methods in jQuery, but nothing seems to work.

What i want to do is when user clicks on sign in button with a class of `.signin` , to toggle a class named `.menu-open` . and then, i want alert something when i click on that button again!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".signin").click(function(e) {          
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".signin").toggleClass("menu-open");
});
 $('.menu-open').on('click', function() {
  alert("SUCCESS");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because on the page load there is no element with class of `.menu-open` in the document so the query silently fails, you should delegate the event.

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu-open', function() {
   alert("SUCCESS");
});
```

Note that using a static parent element is more efficient than using `document` object as the target of delegation.

Comment: I have reached here, thanks to shakti patel for the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/AMLm6/1/

after toggling to remove the .menu-open class, when i click on element only with a .signin class, it alerts! i want to alert it only when the class exist.

Comment: Thanks. but i'm not sure why it doesn't works that way for me.

Answer (score 1):

can you please remove this line

```
e.preventDefault();
```

**preventDefault :**

If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

used this code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".signin").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("menu-open");
     $( ".menu-open" ).bind( "click", function() {
    alert("SUCCESS");
    });     
 });
});
```

working fine check here

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AMLm6/)

Comment: Okey, that works fine , but now the problem is ,after toggling to remove the `.menu-open` class, when i click on element only with a `.signin` class, it alerts! i want to alert it only when the class exist.

http://jsfiddle.net/AMLm6/1/